# NullReferenceException while property change in WPF application

Tags: wpf

In our WPF application, we use the ListBox.But in one particular machine we are getting the null reference exception while adding an item to tree.

we are using .net 3.5.

Below is stack trace and SelectedSharedScene is SelectedItem of tree.

**XAML**

```
<ListBox AutomationProperties.AutomationId="SharedSceneListId"
x:Name="SharedSceneView"
DockPanel.Dock="Top"
BorderThickness="0"
Style="{DynamicResource ListViewStyle}"
KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue"
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource    SharedSceneListTemplate}"
ItemsSource="{Binding SharedScenesCollection}"
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSharedScene}">

Here SharedScenesCollection is just List<SharedScene>
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
    Void OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateSubProperty(DependencyProperty dp)
at System.Windows.Freezable.GetChangeHandlersAndInvalidateSubProperties(EventStorage& calledHandlers)
at System.Windows.Freezable.GetChangeHandlersAndInvalidateSubProperties(EventStorage& calledHandlers)
at System.Windows.Freezable.GetChangeHandlersAndInvalidateSubProperties(EventStorage& calledHandlers)
at System.Windows.Freezable.GetChangeHandlersAndInvalidateSubProperties(EventStorage& calledHandlers)
at System.Windows.Freezable.FireChanged()
at System.Windows.Freezable.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty dp)
at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Invalidate(Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ScheduleTransfer(Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
at MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.NewValueAvailable(Boolean dependencySourcesChanged, Boolean initialValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(Int32 k, ICollectionView collectionView, Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.OnDependencyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyProperty dp, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
at MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.OnSourceInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyProperty dp, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.HandlePropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.OnPropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.DependentList.InvalidateDependents(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs sourceArgs)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty dp)
at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Invalidate(Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ScheduleTransfer(Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
at MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.NewValueAvailable(Boolean dependencySourcesChanged, Boolean initialValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(Int32 k, ICollectionView collectionView, Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
at MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.OnSourcePropertyChanged(Object o, String propName)
at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.System.Windows.IWeakEventListener.ReceiveWeakEvent(Type managerType, Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEventToList(Object sender, EventArgs args, ListenerList list)
at System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventManager.OnPropertyChanged(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
at Lutron.Gulliver.UIFramework.NotifiableDependencyObjectBase.OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
at Lutron.Gulliver.UIFramework.NotifiableDependencyObjectBase.RaisePropertyChangedEvent(String propertyName)
at Lutron.Gulliver.QuantumResi.Programming.SharedSceneTreeViewModel.set_SelectedSharedScene(PresetModelView value)
at Lutron.Gulliver.QuantumResi.Programming.SharedSceneTreeViewModel.AddSharedScene(Object parameter)
at Lutron.Gulliver.UIFramework.WpfCore.DelegateCommand`1.Execute(T parameter)
at Lutron.Gulliver.UIFramework.WpfCore.DelegateCommand`1.System.Windows.Input.ICommand.Execute(Object parameter)
at MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource commandSource, Boolean userInitiated)
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
at System.Windows.UIElement.CrackMouseButtonEventAndReRaiseEvent(DependencyObject sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Comment: Are there differences between the installed .Net frameworks?

Comment: That stack trace will mean nothing to anybody who doesn't have access to your source code. Can you share code for a minimal working sample of the problem? Can you describe in a little more detail what's going on? The issue is happening within data binding somewhere; sharing your Xaml would be a good start...

Comment: issue with your Style ListViewStyle something isn't getting created, try it without setting this style